# Synchronise angular - .NET application with google Calendar API

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, google-calendar-api

I want to integrate the Google Calenar API in my angular .NET application using OAuth2 so every user can see his own calendar whenever he logs in.

I'd like to save the generated code into the database.

I started doing this and in angular side i add this function which can connect to your google calendar and get your private code then send it to back side:

```
  handleAuthClick() {
    let self = this;
    gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().grantOfflineAccess()
      .then(value => {
        const optionsParams = {
          params: new HttpParams()
            .set('code', value.code)
        };
        self.http.get("http://localhost:59933/api/UserCode", optionsParams)
          .subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data);
          })
      });
  }
```

Now i want to use this code to retrieve calendar data whenever a user logged in to the app (whiteout needing to connect another time to the google calendar)

And i started with this but there is nothing about OAuth2 here :

https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/dotnet

Any help? and thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that you are saving the user's refresh token in your database together with your own custom ID for that user.

To understand this, familiarize yourself with [OAuth2](https://oauth.net/2/).

Basically:

- you will send the refresh token to Google in conjunction with your application ID.
- Google will receive this, check if the user you are trying to authorize (refresh token) is still allowing your application (application ID) to proceed.

  - If that's the case Google will reply with an Access Token that has an expiration date.
  - If Google thinks your refresh token and/or your application ID are invalid, it will reject your request. When this happens, you will have to go thru the whole "connect to calendar" steps again.

While the access token in valid, you can use it in your application to fetch the data without prompting your user for more information.

Comment: Well thanks but i think that you have a little mistake. With Oauth2 i will use a specific code to get th refresh Token.See this image here : https://developers.google.com/accounts/images/webflow.png

Comment: @zarzou yes, this token is your client ID(refered to as Application ID on my answer)